# Included rewrite rules not matched

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, wordpress, http-headers

With Apache, I'm trying to set up a rewrite rule which will be included in several virtual hosts. Actually, this rule file is included in 2 vhost.

The first vhost contains only this rewrite rule (and it works) and is acting as a reverse proxy for Nginx :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 Include /etc/apache2/bad-referers
```

The other one contains a Wordpress with W3 Total Cache plugin with its Apache conf and the default WP .htaccess :

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.tld$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

    Include /etc/apache2/bad-referers
    Include /var/www/d/domain.tld/w3tc.conf
```

The bad-referers, in this case is never matched, while this rule ended with [F,L]. The domain name rewriting and W3 Total Cache rules works well. I really do not understand.

Does the order or placement of Include directives matter ? May I have to put the content of all those files in the vhost directive ? Or the RewriteBase ?

The (almost) full vhost via /server-info :

In file: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.tld`

```
   1: <VirtualHost *:80>
   7:   <Directory /var/www/d/domain.tld/html/>
  14:     RewriteEngine On
  16:     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.tld$
  17:     RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

In file: `/etc/apache2/bad-referers`

```
   2:     RewriteEngine on
   5:     RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 4webmasters\.org [NC,OR]
 104:     RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} youporn-forum\.uni\.me [NC]
 105:     RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

In file: `/var/www/d/domain.tld/w3tc.conf`

```
 191:     RewriteEngine On
 192:     RewriteBase /wp-content/cache/minify/
 193:     RewriteRule /w3tc_rewrite_test$ ../../plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?w3tc_rewrite_test=1 [L]
 194:     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
 195:     RewriteRule .* - [E=APPEND_EXT:.gzip]
 196:     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}%{ENV:APPEND_EXT} -f
 197:     RewriteRule (.*) $1%{ENV:APPEND_EXT} [L]
 198:     RewriteRule ^(.+/[X]+\.css)$ ../../plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?test_file=$1 [L]
 199:     RewriteRule ^(.+\.(css|js))$ ../../plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?file=$1 [L]
 207:     RewriteEngine On
 208:     RewriteBase /
 209:     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
 210:     RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
 211:     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
 212:     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
 213:     RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
 214:     RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(W3\ Total\ Cache/0\.9\.3) [NC]
 215:     RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
 216:     RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]

In file: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.tld`

    :   </Directory>
    : </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the rule in bad-referers.

Comment: Now, there is all the rewrite rules of the virtual host.

Comment: Sorry, it's Apache 2.2.16 !

Comment: I can not use END flag... Maybe it will be usefull here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using another method, SetEnvIf & access deny.

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer 4webmasters\.org spambot=yes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=spambot
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you mark your asnwer as valid ? Thanks